# Cannot change startup page in any browser in Windows

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

After installing some program the startup page of my Google Chrome, Firefox and IE changed to http://esurf.biz/?ssid=1444355424&a=1008443. When I open any browser the startup page directs me to some other pages and my antivirus gives warning that am gonna visit pages that contains harmful contents.

Mainly I use Chrome. I tried to change startup page from settings, it didn't worked. So I tried 'Reset Settings', it reset everything except the startup page. The same start up page is still coming.

Also Firefox and IE have this problem. I checked Programs and Features in Control Panel. No program related to this is shown there.
How can I change this issue with startup page ?

---

I checked the answers in the link provided, and tried most of the softwares suggested there. I deleted some suspicious items but it doesn't solved the issue. I can't reinstall OS because its a server and cannot do a reinstallation in the near future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have malware, probably running an active service in the background which resets all homepages to their desired default.

Download and run a reputable malware scanner to confirm.  Personally I prefer a full wipe/reload of a machine which has been infected...

@moderators: Can I make malware scanner recommendations?  If so, malwarebytes has done well for us.

Comment: Malwarebytes is already recommended in the well known duplicate question [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360)

Comment: A scan with MalwareBytes after updating its definition and deleting all the detected items and a restart solved the issue.